# How to get a batch response from google vision text detection API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm currently using google vision's `text_detection` API for single images but I want to get batch responses. I attempted using `BatchAnnotateImagesRequest`, but I haven't got it working as of yet.

What i'm doing for getting a response for one image.

`client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()`

 `with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()`

`image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations`

Answer (score 0):

There's information regarding batch requests to Google's text detection API in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#vision_async_batch_annotate_images-python).

In the documentation you can find some samples written in python you could use to do batch requests, with a limit of 2000 files per batch:

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import enums
import six

def sample_async_batch_annotate_images(input_image_uri, output_uri):
  """Perform async batch image annotation"""

  client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

  # input_image_uri = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/vision/label/wakeupcat.jpg'
  # output_uri = 'gs://your-bucket/prefix/'

  if isinstance(input_image_uri, six.binary_type):
    input_image_uri = input_image_uri.decode('utf-8')
  if isinstance(output_uri, six.binary_type):
    output_uri = output_uri.decode('utf-8')
  source = {'image_uri': input_image_uri}
  image = {'source': source}
  type_ = enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION
  features_element = {'type': type_}
  type_2 = enums.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES
  features_element_2 = {'type': type_2}
  features = [features_element, features_element_2]
  requests_element = {'image': image, 'features': features}
  requests = [requests_element]
  gcs_destination = {'uri': output_uri}

  # The max number of responses to output in each JSON file
  batch_size = 2
  output_config = {'gcs_destination': gcs_destination, 'batch_size': batch_size}

  operation = client.async_batch_annotate_images(requests, output_config)

  print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
  response = operation.result()

  # The output is written to GCS with the provided output_uri as prefix
  gcs_output_uri = response.output_config.gcs_destination.uri
  print('Output written to GCS with prefix: {}'.format(gcs_output_uri))
```

Along the sample code you can also find sample of the output you can expect when executing the batched request. More information regarding batch requests can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#sample_code).